# How asp will recognize user?

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies

As i know, asp recognize the user based on session id and the session id stores in cookie.

If i delete the browser cookie then session id also will be deleted, then how asp recognizes user in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its creates a new cookie and its see him as a new/different user.

The users (mainly) can recognize by two cookies - the one is for the session, and the other is the authorization cookie, if the user is logged in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The scenario is. user logged in and navigate to submit order page. Now user cleared the cookie. After clearing cookie, clicking on Submit order button. As you told it will be treated as a new/different user. Now my doubt is, do user need to login again? If not then how you can say it treating him as as a new/different user.

Comment: @Neeraj When is submit a form, and you hold him by their cookies, and for some reason this cookies are expired, then the submit will fail. No items on cart, no valid user - you probably see a redirect to login page - or nothing on cart.

Comment: @Neeraj a good way to avoid this expiration is to have a unique id on the url that specify the cart and maybe the user that use it - so even if the session expired you can have the id of the cart and the user.